# What is the value of $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{a_{n}}{n}$?

Tags: limits, elementary-number-theory

We have the sequence $(a_{n})_{n\geq1}$ with $a_{n}=$"the sum of digits in base 10 of $n^{2}$". What is the value of $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{a_{n}}{n}$ ?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $a_n \le 9 \cdot (\log_{10} n^2 + 1)$

Hope you can take it from here:)